# Storing complex XML file in MySQL using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am currently working with an XML API that sends me a huge XML file and a matching `.xsd` file. In the `.xsd` file, there are several fields restricted with enumerations. When parsing the XML into a JavaScript Object using `xml2js`, I only get the string value of the field, not an enum that represents it's value. Since it's more efficient storing an integer than a string, it'd be nice to actually be able to do this.

I haven't been able to find a way to parse my XML files in such a way that the object the package returns contains the enums rather than the actual value of the field, and I'm wondering if there is actually a package out there which supports it. As far as I'm able to see, `libxmljs` does not support this either (however, this package has terrible documentation).

Is there a NodeJS package that parses XML strings / files and returns an integer based on the `.xsd` specification?

An example of the specification:

```
<xs:element name="Status">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Status1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Status2" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Status3" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Status4" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Status5" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Status6" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Status7" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Status8" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Status9" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

These values are not the actual values, however, I want to be able to store an integer matching the string that I read from the XML file

```
<Status>Option8</Status>
```

Comment: I am working on a similar problem here, which I haven't solved yet. I am using marklogic to save xml documents though.

Comment: I have figured out that "enumerations" are not the same as what they are in C++ and similar languages. I decided to not store my files in MySQL but rather in a document database